# Questions around the number of subgroups of a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ pe a $p$ group. I have to show that

- the number of nonnormal subgroups is divisible by $p$
- the number of subgroups differs from the number of normal subgroups by a power of $p$.

Are there any theorem that can help me to prove this ? We have discussed the Sylow theorems but I don't know how to apply them - if those are the theorems I need.
(Does this theorem also hold for infinite groups $G$ ?)

Comment: Have you seen the class equation? http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_Class_Equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:*
$G$ operates on the set of subgroups by conjugation.
What are the possible lengths of orbits? What does it mean if the orbit length is $1$?

*Remark:* We don't use finiteness of $G$ here, but the subgroup counts involved should be finite for the statement to make sense.

Comment: If the orbit has length $1$ that means the subgroup is normal (the other direction also holds). But I don't know how to get the length of orbits for nonnormal subgroups. Could you help me there ?

Comment: Orbit lengths divide the group order